# How to recove corrupted XAML (encryption)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, corrupt

Today I opened my Xamarin project, but my main XAML file looks like this!

Not all files look like this, the editor is ok.

I have no backup file for this one, is there any way to fix the file?

[image: Corrupted XAML file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bite the bullet, recreate the view.

Next time use a version control service such that you always have a version of your code to fall back to. Github and other services provide free private repositories if you don't want your code to be public.

Always back up...

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, thank you Cheesebaron. Seems like I really need to try the service you mentioned.

Comment: But can you know the reason for what happened? Why did this happen to that particular file? Is it a virus?

Comment: It can happen due to many reasons. I.e. shutting down the computer while the file is being saved. You could perhaps try to open it with a hex editor and see if you could get the text out.

Comment: Thanks, I tried hex editor but not work. I think it is the reason you said, I remember that I have to "End task" the vs while saving because it freesed :( Thanks dear, I will recreate the view. The problem is that I cannot remember it. The code behind will help me to remember the controls names. Thanks again